# Canvas clear as user drag/pan on screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ionic2, gesture

I'm facing a problem that I really don't know where to start solving, so I hope this question isn't too broad.

I'm making and app that on a screen I'll have a rectangle with some information (let's say it's a `<ion-grid>`) and I need to cover that rectangle with another one so, as que user slides it's finger on the screen, it'll reveal the content behind it.

The first solution that have came in mind is using canvas, and i've seen some exemples of removing a circle from a canvas rectangle on click. The case is i don't know anything about canvas and i don't have a code to share, i'll try something and then edit my question.

The second solution is a (ugly) workaround, making something like:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-5 (pan)='somethingToHideTheCol()'></ion-col> //width-5 or less
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

So as the `<ion-col>` gets panned it calls a function that hides it or changes the background to transparent.

The second solution'll not imitate the user's finger shape, it'll be more ugly but maybe works. The first solution with a canvas would be better, but i don't know where to start, so:

- How can i do this?
- Is it possible to use canvas with Ionic 2?
- how to grab via javascript that the user is sliding/dragging his finger on the screen?
- Is there a better solution than any of these two? Like an drawing library or something like this.

Any idea, code, link, tutorial is a help. Thanks :)

### EDIT

This is the effect i want to create:

[image: Finger on screen effect]

So as the user touch and drag his finger on screen it'll delete part of the canvas.

Comment: I updated my answer after your last question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas is indeed the way to go :)
All you have to do is place a canvas over your element, fill the canvas's background and then use the CompositeOperations to be able to remove part of that background:

```js
var CanvasHide = function(settings) {
  this.mouseDown = false;
 this.el = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-canvas-hide]");
 this.init = function() {
   var self = this;
   for (var i=0, l=this.el.length; i<l; i++) {
     self.addCanvas(this.el[i]);
    }
  }
  
  this.addCanvas = function(el) {
    var self = this;
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = el.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = el.offsetHeight;
    el.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.onmousedown=function(){self.mouseDown=true;};
    canvas.onmouseup=function(){self.mouseDown=false;};
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (self.mouseDown) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x - settings.radius/2, y - settings.radius/2, settings.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  }
  
  this.init();
}

var canvasHide = new CanvasHide({radius:20});
```

```css
*[data-canvas-hide] {
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" data-canvas-hide>
<h1>
Title
</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In commodi odio, incidunt saepe aperiam nam rerum at ex consequatur tempora quae temporibus. Odio, facere repudiandae suscipit doloribus autem unde tempore qui earum illum, minima consequatur officia repellat labore, doloremque eveniet amet eligendi quam aspernatur quisquam inventore pariatur temporibus. Ducimus adipisci numquam quaerat. Atque doloremque nostrum blanditiis dicta repellendus, provident, dolorum modi praesentium perferendis animi ab. Eaque totam itaque quo provident ea sint explicabo dicta adipisci doloremque ipsam, voluptate. Quisquam maxime ipsa fugit magnam tempora, exercitationem minus. Amet doloremque vero consequuntur perferendis voluptate perspiciatis eaque, assumenda inventore, quibusdam molestias obcaecati quis.</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: To make it work on touch devices you need to change the mouseevents to touchevents.

Comment: This is good, rly liked it and if i can't get to the canva solution will use this. I updated the question with the effect i want to achieve, that's why i think i need canvas.

Comment: I edited my answer, click and drag to reveal the hidden text. I have written the js part so, that it will create the overlay canvas for every element that has the data-canvas-hide attribute.

Comment: it worked perfectly fine with the click, for the touchevents i can't get to reveal the text. To get the X and Y coordinates i'm using `x = e.touches[0].clientX`, is this right? Will build and try on the phone instead of chrome DevTools.

Comment: Yes it should be correct. It's definitely better to always test on the real device when working with touch events.

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM, thank you so much sir. The only extra thing i needed to do is add a variable `var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();` and on the position make it like `e.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;` because it was clearing a little bellow the finger. Tomorrow i'l award you the bounty. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The canvas is almost always the best way to do any form of graphics works.

Seams i did not write fast enough to get an answer in. Well rather than waste the code, here is another version of canvas.

I use requestAnimationFrame to update the canvas as the mouse can fire at very high rates. Rendering from IO events is never a good idea and this is more so with mouse events.

Also included simple touch interface and a few ways to mess with the way the canvas is drawn to produce different FX rather than just a erase. Ultimately this would be best done in WebGL and a shader that simulates the scratch reveal surface, orientation sensors etc for additional diffuse specular shading FX to give a very high quality feel to the interface.

```js
var divBounds = textDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
// create two so we can add some FX
var canvasA = document.createElement("canvas");  // this one is for display
var canvasB = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasB.width = canvasA.width = divBounds.width;
canvasB.height = canvasA.height = divBounds.height;
canvasA.style.position = "absolute";
canvasA.style.top = divBounds.top + "px"
canvasA.style.left = divBounds.left + "px"
var ctxA = canvasA.getContext("2d");
var ctxB = canvasB.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvasA);


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Mouse and touch interface
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
const input = (function(){
    var deviceIO;
    // use navigator.maxTouchPoints to discover if device has touch caps.
    if(navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0){
        deviceIO = function(element){
            const canvasPixelScale = 1; // not used
            var top = 0;  // offset to element
            var left = 0; 
            var touch = {
                x : 0,  // primary touch point
                y : 0,
                points : [], // all touch points
                count : 0,  // count of active touches.
                isTouched : false, // true if touched
                events : "touchstart,touchmove,touchend,touchcancel".split(","),
            }
            // aliases for the lazy programmer
            var t = touch;
            var TP = touch.points;
            
            
            // functions to track touch points
            // Rather than create new touch points all the time this code uses a pre allocated array of touch points
            // to track individual touch points.            
            function newTouch(){ // returns a new (empty) touch
                for(var j = 0; j < touch.pCount; j ++){if(TP[j].id === -1){return TP[j]}}
            }
            function getTouch(id){ // returns a touch by its id
                for(var j = 0; j < touch.pCount; j ++) {if (TP[j].id === id) {return TP[j]}}            
            }
            // sets the coordinates of a touch point
            function setTouch(touchPoint, touchItem, ending){
                if(!ending){
                    touchPoint.dx = touchItem.pageX / canvasPixelScale - touchPoint.x;
                    touchPoint.dy = touchItem.pageY / canvasPixelScale - touchPoint.y;
                }
                touchPoint.x = (touchItem.pageX / canvasPixelScale) - left;
                touchPoint.y = (touchItem.pageY / canvasPixelScale) - top;        
            }
            // handle all touch events
            function touchEvent(event){
                event.preventDefault();    
                var tp;
                var e = event;
                var cT = event.changedTouches;
                // ensure page offset is correct by updating it each event
                var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect()
                left = bounds.left + scrollX; 
                top = bounds.top + scrollY; 
                
                if(event.type === "touchstart"){
                    for(var i = 0; i < cT.length; i ++){
                        var tp = newTouch();
                        setTouch(tp,cT[i]);
                        tp.dx = 0; 
                        tp.dy = 0; 
                        tp.id = cT[i].identifier;
                    }
                }else if(event.type === "touchmove"){
                    for(var i = 0; i < cT.length; i ++){
                        setTouch(getTouch(cT[i].identifier),cT[i]);
                    }
                }else if(event.type === "touchend"){
                    for(var i = 0; i < cT.length; i ++){
                        setTouch(tp = getTouch(cT[i].identifier),cT[i],true);
                        tp.id = -1;
                    }
                }else if(event.type === "touchcancel"){
                    for(var i = 0; i < cT.length; i ++){
                        var tp = getTouch(cT[i].identifier);
                        tp.id = -1;
                    }
                }
                //check for any active touch events. If none turn off touch flag
                touch.isTouched = false;
                touch.count = 0;
                for(var j = 0; j < touch.pCount; j ++) {
                    if (TP[j].id !== -1) {            
                        if(touch.count === 0){  // use the first touch point as main input coord
                            touch.x = TP[j].x;
                            touch.y = TP[j].y;
                        }
                        touch.isTouched = true;
                        touch.count += 1;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            touch.pCount = navigator.maxTouchPoints;
            for(var i = 0; i < touch.pCount; i ++){// create a set of touch points that persist 
                touch.points[i] = { x : 0,y : 0,dx : 0,dy : 0,down : false,id : -1,}                
            }
            touch.events.forEach(n => { element.addEventListener(n, touchEvent); } );        
            return touch;
        }
    }else{  // use the mouse instead
        deviceIO = function(element){
            function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
            var i;
            var mouse = {
                x : 0, y : 0, buttonRaw : 0,
                over : false,  // mouse is over the element
                bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
                mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover".split(",")
            };
            function mouseMove(e) {
                var t = e.type;
                var m = mouse;
                var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect()
                m.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX; 
                m.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY; 
                if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1];
                } else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
                } else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false;
                } else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            mouse.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );

            return mouse;
        }
    }  
    return deviceIO;
}());

const io = input(canvasA); // start user input

//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Scratchy
//------------------------------------------------------------------
const message = "Touch!"; // message on canvas
const font = "68px arial black"; // text for message
const fontCol = "#777"; // colour off message
// the display settings for app
const drawWidth = 40; // radius of touch area
const edgeStyle = "#777"; // colour of overlay
const edgeWidth = 4; // make look nice
const overlayStyle = "#999"; // colour of overlay
const displayAccentMain = "rgba(80,160,255,1)"; // make look nice
const displayAccent = "rgba(60,60,60,1)";
const touchPointFalloffA = 1.1; // shift center of s curve. Less than one and like touch press harder more than one and make touch more like feather scratching glass
const touchPointFalloffB = 2; // strength off s curve
var lastX;
var lastY; // save the position of last touch mouse
const touchStyle = createTouchStyle(touchPointFalloffA, touchPointFalloffB); // creates a gradient used to draw the touch point
start(); // start the app;
function createTouchStyle(a,b){
    const touchGradient = ctxA.createRadialGradient(0,0,0,0,0,drawWidth);
    const curveS = (x,p) => {
       x = x < 0 ? 0 : x > 1 ? 1 : x;
       var xx = Math.pow(x,p);
       return xx / (xx + Math.pow(1-x,p));
    };
    const curveB = (x,p) => {
       x = x < 0 ? 0 : x > 1 ? 1 : x;
       return Math.pow(x,p);
    };
    for(var i = 0; i <= 1; i += 0.025){
        touchGradient.addColorStop(i,"rgba(0,0,0,"+curveS(curveB(1-i,a),b)+")");
    }
    return touchGradient;
}

// Draw the starting canvas
function start() {
    ctxB.font = font;
    ctxB.textAlign = "center";
    ctxB.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctxB.fillStyle = edgeStyle;
    ctxB.fillRect(0, 0, canvasA.width, canvasA.height);
    ctxB.fillStyle = overlayStyle;
    ctxB.fillRect(edgeWidth, edgeWidth, canvasA.width - edgeWidth * 2, canvasA.height - edgeWidth * 2);    
    ctxB.fillStyle = fontCol;
    ctxB.fillText(message,canvasB.width / 2, canvasB. height / 2);    
    ctxA.drawImage(canvasB, 0, 0); // put canvas on display
    textDiv.className = "showText"; // set color of text so that it can be read
    update();
}


// update the canvas when there is touch or mouse changes
function update() {
    // only on touch or mouse button down
    if (io.isTouched || io.buttonRaw === 1) {
        if(lastX === undefined){ // if start of touch set last to current
            lastX = io.x;
            lastY = io.y;
        }
        // set gradient and copmosite mode
        ctxB.fillStyle = touchStyle;
        ctxB.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

        // If large movement then smear the couch over the distance
        // Find the distance from last contact point / mouse down
        var dx = io.x - lastX;
        var dy = io.y - lastY;
        var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        if(dist > 1.5){  // only smear out contact if dist over 1.5 pixels
            lastX += (dx /= dist);  // normalise vector between contacts
            lastY += (dy /= dist);  // also step past last pos as that has been drawn
            dist += 1;
            ctxB.globalAlpha = Math.max(0.05,1 / dist); // reduce FX depending on dist
            while(dist > 0){ // move from last to current
                ctxB.beginPath();
                ctxB.setTransform(1,0,0,1,lastX,lastY);
                ctxB.arc(0, 0, drawWidth, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctxB.fill();
                lastX += dx;
                lastY += dy;
                dist -= 1;
            }
        }else{        
            // just a single touch point
            ctxB.globalAlpha = 1.0;
            ctxB.setTransform(1,0,0,1,io.x,io.y);
            ctxB.beginPath();
            ctxB.arc(0, 0, drawWidth, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctxB.fill();
        }
        // save this pos for the next frame
        lastX = io.x;
        lastY = io.y;
        
        // draw to display canvas using shadows to add FX

        ctxA.clearRect(0,0,canvasA.width,canvasA.height);
        // Add to display canvas with very slight highlight
        ctxA.shadowOffsetX = ctxA.shadowOffsetY = 1;
        ctxA.shadowColor = displayAccentMain;
        ctxA.drawImage(canvasB, 0, 0);

        ctxA.shadowOffsetX = ctxA.shadowOffsetY = -1;
        ctxA.shadowColor = displayAccent;
        ctxA.drawImage(canvasB, 0, 0);

    }else{
        lastX = undefined; // no contact no last contact!
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
div {
    font-family : arial black;
    font-size : 16px;
}
#textDiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 4px #fff solid;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
}  
.hideText {
    background: #999;
    color: #999;
}
.showText {  /* because the canvas is added after the div is displayed */
         /* the above style hides the text and this make is visible */
         /* when canvas is ready */
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
 

}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2>Test touch</h2>    
    <div id="textDiv" class="hideText">
        <h3>From MDN TouchEvent</h3>
        <p>The TouchEvent interface represents an event sent when the state of contacts with a touch-sensitive surface changes. This surface can be a touch screen or trackpad, for example. The event can describe one or more points of contact with the screen and includes support for detecting movement, addition and removal of contact points, and so forth.</p>
        <p>Touches are represented by the Touch object; each touch is described by a position, size and shape, amount of pressure, and target element. Lists of touches are represented by TouchList objects</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, liked your code so much, the blur effect it creates when erasing the canvas is awesome. Thank you for sharing, will definitely study it.